# Set system proxy && authentication in C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, proxy, proxy-authentication

Is there a way in C++ to set the Windows system proxy **with authentication credentials** so it would affect all running programs(browsers, etc...) immediatly but:

1. Not requiring restarting any browser
2. **Not requiring browser-reauthentication**

I am looking really for a system level pre-authenticated proxy.

Thank you for any help. Ask any questions if something is unclear.

*Using: c++11, Windows 7*

**EDIT 1:** I need to set this programmatically, so please do not suggest any manual actions.

**EDIT 2:** Partially acceptable is a way how to set proxy programmatically without pre-authentication but still keeping 1. requirement (Not requiring restarting any browser)

Comment: Are you willing to use 3rd party libraries to make this happen or natively in your code?

Comment: @positron Why not, I just want to achieve the goal - preauthenticated proxy set on system level :) I am using Windows' libraries anyway...

Answer (score 1):

System-level proxy settings are located in registry under `\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` hive in `HKLM` for all users and `HKCU` hive for current user.
There is an official [instruction](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819961/en-us) how to change it via REG file, you does not need to write any code.

But the main problem is: any application may have its own proxy settings, where it 1) can *prefer* system level settings but allow to override it by user, 2) not using system settings at all.

In corporate environments this problem solves as:

1. Internet gateway not allowed directly access to external network any computer except proxy server (Microsoft ISA/Forefront Web Proxy)
2. Proxy settings in registry are forced to all computers via Group Policies
3. If user need to run application which can not use system-wide proxy settings - it need to install ISA Firewall Client which intercepts all traffic and authenticate it on the ISA proxy.

So when you use full Microsoft software stack - you still not need to write any code :-)
Moreover, ISA Firewall Client uses [undocumented Windows features](http://www.isaserver.org/articles-tutorials/configuration-security/Understanding-ISA-Firewall-Client-Part1.html) and it will be too hard to write something to replace it with your own "C++11" skills.

Comment: Those settings don't appear to include a password.  But I suppose the OP could point them to a proxy server running locally on the box, and have that proxy server forward the requests via the authenticated proxy.

Comment: Well, your "C++11 code" will be "int main() { system("reg add settings.reg");}"
And BTW - changing proxy settings **DOES NOT** require browser to restart.

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned it in my answer - you can not control applications that use own proxy settings instead of microsoft one. 
You can "raise change notice" calling `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` for proxy settings keys, and good application will re-read it, but many other applications will still use old data. There is no ultimate solution and you need to find solution for concrete application you are using.

Comment: @vitalyster btw sorry I've mistunderstood you before - of course changing the settings - just changing them - does not require browser restart (it's a registry...) I was talking about changing it in the browser/app => in other words reloading it :)

Comment: Just tested `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` => at least Chrome does not get it.